# Slam_gmapping tutorial problem with time sync on rosbag

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I finished gmapping tutorial and started rosbag play and slam_gmapping (rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan). I needed to read tf from that gmapping, lets say between odom->map.

Once started rosbag and slam_gmapping time wasn't right, solved it with 'param set /use_sim_time true' before starting rosbag.
With the code bellow I was reading tf and got this values:

x = 1134749241 y = -1078897170 z = -1255994495

x = 1134749241 y = -1078897170 z = -1255994495

x = 1134749241 y = -1078897170 z = -1255994495

x = 1134749241 y = -1078897170 z = -1255994495

- not same every time, only in this example <- not an issue

Those values are too big to be real tf, so i need help with correct reading of tf from rosbag AND slam_gmapping.

Code to read tf:

```
tf::TransformListener listener;

ros::Rate rate(1.0);
while (nh.ok()){
tf::StampedTransform tfTransform;

try { 
    listener.lookupTransform("/odom",
    "/map",       
    ros::Time(0), 
    tfTransform);
}
catch(tf::TransformException &exception) { 
    ROS_ERROR("%s", exception.what());
}

ROS_INFO("%d %d %d", tfTransform.getOrigin().x(), tfTransform.getOrigin().y(), tfTransform.getOrigin().z());
rate.sleep();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56475/slam_gmapping-tutorial-problem-with-time-sync-on-rosbag/) by [mdm](https://answers.ros.org/users/4311/mdm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey have u published clock while playing bag file using --clock parameter??
Also try tf_echo for getting transformation between map and odom.
Once u plat bag file just run following command in new terminal

rosrun tf tf_echo /map /odom

If u get correct tf then there is a bug in ur code but if this command is also publishing same tf as u have mentioned in ur question then there is a problem with the way you are playing bag file.

Try using this code:

`tf::StampedTransform transform;
try{`

listener.waitForTransform("map", "/robot1/odom",ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(0.1));
listener.lookupTransform("map", "/robot1/odom",
ros::Time(0), transform);
}
catch (tf::TransformException ex){
ROS_ERROR("Error looking up transformation\n%s",ex.what());
return;
}

This works fine for me..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mdm](https://answers.ros.org/users/4311/mdm/) on 2013-02-28**:
now i totally lost you.
there is no frame "/robot1/odom" anywhere. i did tf monitor and there isn't any with that name/id

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-28**:
Sorry i just copied it from my own code which looks for tf between "/robot1/odom" and map. Replace that with odom and test it.

**Comment by [mdm](https://answers.ros.org/users/4311/mdm/) on 2013-02-28**:
did that and i says "frame /map doesn't exist"

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-28**:
ok do one thing play rosbag file with clock and see the complete tf tree and check where odom is defined..map should exist as u said ur getting transformation wen you use tf_echo..